# Angularjs md-datepicker month issue

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I'm using angular 1.5.8 and I have a strange behaviour with this md-datepicker. It works perfect, but only on the day 31st, any day you pick from the next month, it will save the same date but in two months in advance.
For example, today is the 31st of October. If I pick any date 1st of November, it will save 1st of December.
This issue occurres ONLY when you do the save on the day 31st. I tried yesterday and it was working properly.
My question is: does anybody know if this is a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: share the code or add js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

The same issue what you are telling can't be seen in md-datepicker demo of AngularJsMaterial website.
One more question I have is, are you making use of $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate() / $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate().
If yes, it's better to create a plunker code to get into the issue. If you are making use of parseDate/formatDate one more thing I would suggest is to go through how [new Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) works.
If you check reference you would see that 
**month**
*- Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.*